# How to properly filter a NSArray using a NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to find the `tags` inside a `NSDictionary` inside `myAr` that matches the criteria of `str` and I want the result that has `only` those exact arrays no more nor less. In this example I want only the 2nd `NSDictionary` of `myAr`.

I though of trying to achieve this by using a predicate but that always returns empty when i use arrays.

I am trying to filter using an array but this is not working. I was wondering if anyone could tell me what i am doing wrong and how could i achieve my objective. thanks in advance

```
  NSArray * myAr = @[ @{ @"tags": @[@"one",@"two",@"three"],
                           @"number": @"4"
                          },
                        @{ @"tags": @[@"one",@"two"],
                           @"number":@"4"
                        },
                        @{ @"tags": @[@"one",@"two",@"four"],
                           @"number":@"4"
                        },
                        @{ @"tags": @[@"chacho",@"chocho"],
                           @"number":@"4"
                        },
                        @{ @"tags": @[@"one"],
                           @"number":@"4"
                        } ];

    NSArray* str = @[@"one",@"two"];
    NSPredicate* pre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tags CONTAINS %@ ",str];
    myAr = [myAr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pre];
    NSLog(@"%@",myAr);
```

Comment: the block-based pedicates are more convenient, and with them you would not be in same siruation.

Comment: I don't really understand why the question is so heavily downvoted. Jonathan has (almost) clearly described what he wants, and provided small complete self-contained sample code. - I don't understand either why some answers are downvoted ...

Comment: Please don't [delete and immediately repost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067919/how-to-filter-content-in-nsarray-using-predicate). Edit your original instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just have to replace "CONTAINS" by "="
in the predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tags = %@ ",str]
```

This gives an array with all dictionaries where the "tags" value is equal to the
given array `str`. In your example, it returns an array with the second dictionary
only.

**UPDATE:** To find all dictionaries where the "tags" value is an array with the
given elements, but *independent of the order*, the following slightly more
complicated predicate should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tags.@count = %d AND SUBQUERY(tags, $t, $t in %@).@count = %d",
     [str count], str, [str count]];
```

**UPDATE 2:** That was too complicated, the following predicate seems to work as well:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tags.@count = %d AND ALL tags in %@",
    [str count], str]
```

(I have assumed that `str` contains only *different* elements.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I can not do direct comparision like that as the order of the array my change. this if then  my array is `@[@"two",@"one"];` it wont find it. thats why i though of using `contains`

Comment: also my array criteria is dynamic, thus sometimes will have 1,2  or more items that will compare against

Comment: Thank you!... I didn't how to make that complex subquery. Could i ask you what are `$t` so that i can learn for next time?

Comment: @JonathanThurft: See updated answer again, you don't really need a SUBQUERY here.

Comment: @JonathanThurft: In the SUBQUERY, the "local variable" `$t` is set to all `tags` in turn, and for each tag the predicate is evaluated. So `SUBQUERY(tags, $t, $t in %@)` is the set of tags that are in `%@`.

Answer (score 1):

For an answer that uses neither a for loop nor predicate format strings, try using a block and make use of NSSet to determine if the set of tags you want to match is equal to a set of the array element's tags. For example:

```
NSSet* desiredTags = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"one", @"two", nil];

NSPredicate *tagFilterPredicate = [NSPredicate
    predicateWithBlock:^BOOL (id data, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        NSSet *tags = [NSSet setWithArray:[data objectForKey:@"tags"]];
        return [desiredTags isEqual:tags];
    }];

NSArray *resultArray = [myArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:tagFilterPredicate];
```

Bear in mind that this *does* allocate a set per iteration. So, if you're looking to avoid allocations, this is not adequate. Otherwise, it at least avoids a format string.

Comment: Yes this works as well. (I think the `tags &&` check is not really needed.)

Comment: Woops -- the `tags &&` check was from an earlier version of the answer I was drafting.

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force way to do this would be to remove your predicate and just enumerate:

```
NSArray *required = @[@"one", @"two"];
NSMutableArray *matches = [@[] mutableCopy];
[myAr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
      BOOL match = YES;
      for (NSString *item in required) {
        if (![obj containsObject:item]) {
          match = NO;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (match && [(NSArray *)obj count] == required.count) {
        [matches addObject:obj];
      }
    }
  }];
}];
```

Comment: This would return all matches with that criteria an not the object that only hast those 2 and it will also only return items that have just 1 of those. also the criteria will dynamicaly change.

Comment: Your original question used the keyword "CONTAINS" which means just that—contains "one" and "two", which was confusing. I have updated my answer. Updated my answer to match your needs.

Comment: @MartinR's answer is solid for using predicate, though my updated brute-force method would also work now.

Comment: That now works. but still doesn't account for dynamic criteria. given that the objects to include are dynamic

Comment: Updated to allow for dynamic criteria.